# flask-admin one to many inline_models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I use Flask Admin's inline_models, the system throws a debugging message.

```
 File "/Users/user/Desktop/flask_venv/flask/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/form.py", line 678, in _calculate_mapping_key_pair
    raise Exception('Cannot find reverse relation for model %s' % info.model)
Exception: Cannot find reverse relation for model <class 'myproject.models.Ordersinq'>
```

The following code are my models:

```
class Orders(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'

    Order_no = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    Prod_no = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True)
    Prod_quan = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True)
    Merch_no = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    
    ordersinq= db.relationship('Ordersinq', back_populates='order')

class Ordersinq(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ordersinq'
    no = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    orders_no = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('orders.Order_no', ondelete="CASCADE"))
    
    order=db.relationship("Orders", back_populates="ordersinq")
```

Orders is one, Ordersinq is many

I tried many way to solve it, but it seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

redundant on `orders_no` and `order` field on table `Ordersinq`. The field `orders_no` is the correct one since it is required on many-to-one relation with table `Orders`. This should work.

```
class Orders(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'

    Order_no = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    Prod_no = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True)
    Prod_quan = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True)
    Merch_no = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    
    ordersinq= db.relationship('Ordersinq', backref='orders')

class Ordersinq(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ordersinq'
    no = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    orders_no = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('orders.Order_no', ondelete="CASCADE"))
```

Comment: You're confusing `backref`and `back_populates`; with `back_populates` you indeed must specify the back_populates relation on both sides

Comment: I tried both `backref` and `back_populates` actually, but it still error. Strangely, my localhost run correctly , but error on server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the letter case of models.

Fix:

```
class Orders(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'

    Order_no = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    Prod_no = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True)
    Prod_quan = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True)
    Merch_no = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)

    ordersinq = db.relationship('Ordersinq', back_populates='order')

class Ordersinq(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ordersinq'
    no = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    orders_no = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('orders.Order_no', ondelete="CASCADE"))

    order = db.relationship("Orders", back_populates="ordersinq")
```

Comment: Your code is the same with my code...